# Flyte 0.16.2: Error loading Blob - How to get Types.Blob.fetch() to work in task decorated function?

Tags: python, flyte

I have a Flyte task function like this:

```
@task
def do_stuff(framework_obj):
    framework_obj.get_outputs()  # This calls Types.Blob.fetch(some_uri)
```

Trying to load a blob URI using `flytekit.sdk.types.Types.Blob.fetch`, but getting this error:

```
ERROR:flytekit: Exception when executing No temporary file system is present.  Either call this method from within the context of a task or surround with a 'with LocalTestFileSystem():' block.  Or specify a path when calling this function.  Note: Cleanup is not automatic when a path is specified.
```

I can confirm I can load blobs using `with LocalTestFileSystem()`, in tests, but when actually trying to run a workflow, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, as the function that calls blob-processing is decorated with `@task` so it's definitely a Flyte Task. I also confirmed that the task node exists on the Flyte web console.

What path is the error referencing and how do I call this function appropriately?

Using Flyte Version 0.16.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please give a bit more information about the code? This is flytekit version 0.15.x? I'm a bit confused since that version shouldn't have the `@task` decorator.  It should only have `@python_task` which is an older API.  If you want to use the new python native typing API you should install flytekit==0.17.0 instead.

Also, could you point to the documentation you're looking at?  We've updated the docs a fair amount recently, maybe there's some confusion around that.  [These](https://flytecookbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) are the examples worth looking at. There's also two new Python classes, [FlyteFile](https://github.com/flyteorg/flytekit/blob/master/flytekit/types/file/file.py) and [FlyteDirectory](https://github.com/flyteorg/flytekit/blob/master/flytekit/types/directory/types.py) that have replaced the Blob class in flytekit (though that remains what the IDL [type](https://github.com/flyteorg/flyteidl/blob/master/protos/flyteidl/core/types.proto#L47) is called).

(would've left this as a comment but I don't have the reputation to yet.)

Some code to help with fetching outputs and reading from a file output

```
@task
def task_file_reader():
    client = SynchronousFlyteClient("flyteadmin.flyte.svc.cluster.local:81", insecure=True)
    exec_id = WorkflowExecutionIdentifier(
    domain="development",
    project="flytesnacks",
    name="iaok0qy6k1",
    )
    data = client.get_execution_data(exec_id)
    lit = data.full_outputs.literals["o0"]

    ctx = FlyteContext.current_context()
    ff = TypeEngine.to_python_value(ctx, lv=lit, 
    expected_python_type=FlyteFile)
    with open(ff, 'rb') as fh:
        print(fh.readlines())
```